# aws ec2 describe-snapshots does not return Tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to list all snapshots in my account.  I use the following command

```
AWS_PAGER="" aws ec2 describe-snapshots --max-items=1000  --region=us-east-1 --query 'Snapshots[*].{id: SnapshotId,startTime: startTime,tags:Tags[*]}'
```

I have also tried the following:

```
AWS_PAGER="" aws ec2 describe-snapshots --max-items=1000  --region=us-east-1 --query 'Snapshots[*].{id: SnapshotId,startTime: startTime,tags:Tags}'
```

All of the tag entries return **tags: null**

Question: How do I query for a list of snapshots, **along with the tags**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the awscli [describe-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html) feature once you have the snapshot IDs in hand, for example:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags help

aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=snap-1234,snap-5678
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
AWS_PAGER="" aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region=us-east-1 --query "Snapshots[*].{description:Description,ownerId:OwnerId,snapshotId:SnapshotId,tags:Tags}"
```